# Как выкачать видео?

Tags: flash, видео, загрузка, swf

Добрый день. Хочу скачать видео с сайта ([ссылка на страницу](https://sml-csr.ext.hpe.com/results.htm?SID=5177953&MEID=C0EDEDED-CA0B-4146-8B2D-D4FE3B1BD210))

Чтобы открылось видео, нужно нажать на любой пункт слева.
Как выкачать видео?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, требуется уточнение.... Если есть ссылка на ресурс, его можно выкачать любым удобным способом с помощью программ-качалок (те что обычно на ...download заканчиваются) Им только ссылку скармливаешь и все. Если же вопрос про использование кода для скачивания - тут уж точно нужно точно знать язык и т.п.

Comment: @alexoander Мдаа.. Там видео выводит через жопу используя вместо `body` `frameset` и там видео в виде  `<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars=""/>`, так что вопрос сложный.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Мне надо само видео выдрать. Там не так просто выдрать то)

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо именно в `SWF`-формате? Если да, то тогда я немного попарюсь с тем, как их извлечь из очень странного источника, где вместо `body` юзается `franeset`, а вместо блоков `frame`, а если нет, то чего ты не смекнул? Включаешь fullscreen этого видео, и записываешь с помощью `Bandicam` или другой программы для захвата экрана (я использую QuickTime на Mac).

Comment: Ага, именно видео. Но вариант с записью экрана тоже имеет место, если легко не выдрать )

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский  Просто, если вы скачаете `SWF`, то видео будет вместе с плеером.